# How can I stop the npm package react-google-recaptcha component from loading after the page nextjs 13

Tags: javascript, typescript, recaptcha, delay, next.js13

I have the following code wherein I pass the sitekey, ref and hl for language to the ReCAPTCHA component which then because of an asynchronous script call only loads subsequently to the initial page render. I would like some way to delay the page load until the script succeeds or to display the UI immediately regardless of the asynchronous code perhaps disabling it for said period of time. I have considered both using state with a loader and nextjs built in suspense functionality. The problem seems to be that in either case the asyncScriptOnLoad callback will never fire as the component itself is not loaded until the spinner is hidden pending the state change from the callback so catch 22. How might this be achieved?

```js
export default function Contact({ params }: { params: { locale: string } }) {

  const recaptcha = useRef<ReCAPTCHA>(null)


  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false)
  const { locale } = params
  const t = useTranslations('Contact');

  const formSchema = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(1, {
      message: "Username must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
    email: z.string().email().min(1, {
      message: "Invalid email.",
    }),
    mobile: z.string().min(1, {
      message: "Invalid mobile number.",
    }),
    notes: z.string().min(1, {
      message: "Message must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
  });

  // 1. Define your form.
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      mobile: "",
      notes: "",
    },
  });

  const {errors} = form.formState

  const onSubmit = (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
      setSubmitting(true)
      const { name, email, mobile, notes } = values
      const captchaValue = recaptcha.current?.getValue();

      if (!captchaValue) {
        toast.error(t('message2'), {
          position: "top-right",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "light",
        });

      } else {

          axios.post(`/api/verify`, { data: { captcha: captchaValue } })
          .then(function(res) {
            if (res.data.success) {
               axios.post(`/api/contact`, { data: { name, email, mobile, notes } })
               .then(function (value){
                toast.success(t('message1'), {
                  position: "top-right",
                  autoClose: 5000,
                  hideProgressBar: false,
                  closeOnClick: true,
                  pauseOnHover: true,
                  draggable: true,
                  progress: undefined,
                  theme: "light",
                });
                recaptcha.current?.reset()
                form.reset()
                setSubmitting(false)

               })
            }
            else {
              toast.error(t('message2'), {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
                theme: "light",
              });
              setSubmitting(false)

            }
          })


      
      }
    } catch (err) {
      setSubmitting(false)
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col h-screen">
      <NavigationBar locale={locale} />
      <div className=" p-7 sm:p-14 flex-col flex-grow">
        <article className="h-full">
        <ToastContainer />
          <div className="flex-col space-y-8">
            <TypographyH3>{t('title1')}</TypographyH3>
            <div className="flex w-full">
              <div className="w-full sm:w-1/2">
                <Form {...form}>
                  <form
                    onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                    className="space-y-8"
                  >
                    <FormField
                      control={form.control}
                      name="name"
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem>
                          {/* <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel> */}
                          <FormControl>
                            <Input className={`${errors.name ? 'border-solid border-2 border-red-500' : ''} focus-visible:ring-transparent`} placeholder={t('input1')} {...field} />
                          </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                      )}
                    />
                    <FormField
                      control={form.control}
                      name="email"
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem>
                          <FormControl>
                            <Input className={`${errors.email ? 'border-solid border-2 border-red-500' : ''} focus-visible:ring-transparent`} placeholder={t('input2')} {...field} />
                          </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                      )}
                    />
                    <FormField
                      control={form.control}
                      name="mobile"
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem>
                          <FormControl>
                            <Input className={`${errors.mobile ? 'border-solid border-2 border-red-500' : ''} focus-visible:ring-transparent`} placeholder={t('input3')} {...field} />
                          </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                      )}
                    />
                    <FormField
                      control={form.control}
                      name="notes"
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <FormItem>
                          <FormControl>
                            <Textarea
                            className={`${errors.notes ? 'border-solid border-2 border-red-500' : ''} focus-visible:ring-transparent`}
                              placeholder={t('input4')}
                              {...field}
                            />
                          </FormControl>
                        </FormItem>
                      )}
                    />
                    <div className="min-h-[78px]">
                      <ReCAPTCHA hl={locale} ref={recaptcha}  sitekey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_KEY} /> # Recaptcha component experiencing delay
                    </div>
                  

                    <Button disabled={submitting} type="submit">{submitting ? <div className="flex flex-col flex-grow w-full h-full justify-center items-center space-y-8 ">
                      <Loader2 className="h-6 w-6 animate-spin" />
                    </div> : t('button')}</Button>
                  </form>
                </Form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```